# Proof of scaling property of Brownian motion via finite dimensional distributions

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification, stochastic-processes

Let $B_{t}$ be standard brownian motion at set $W_{t}=\frac{1}{c}B_{c^2t}$. The finite dimensonal distributions of $W_{t}$ are,

$P(W_{t_{1}}\in (-\infty,x_{1}], \ldots W_{t_{n}}\in (-\infty,x_{n}])=P(\frac{1}{c}B_{c^2t_{1}}\in (-\infty,x_{1}], \ldots \frac{1}{c}B_{c^2t_{n}}\in (-\infty,x_{n}])=P(B_{c^2t_{1}}\in (-\infty,cx_{1}], \ldots ,B_{c^2t_{n}}\in (-\infty,cx_{n}])= $

$\int_{(-\infty,cx_{1}]\times (-\infty,cx_{n}]}\prod\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi c^2 (t_{i+1}-t_{i})}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2c^2t^2}}\cdots e^{-\frac{x^2}{2c^2(t_{n}-t_{n-1})^2}}dx_{1} \ldots dx_{n}=$

$\int_{(-\infty,x_{1}]\times (-\infty,x_{n}]}\prod\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi c^2 (t_{i+1}-t_{i})}}e^{-\frac{c^2x^2}{2c^2t^2}}\cdots e^{-\frac{c^2x^2}{2c^2(t_{n}-t_{n-1})^2}}dx_{1} \ldots dx_{n}=$

$\int_{(-\infty,x_{1}]\times (-\infty,x_{n}]}\prod\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi c^2 (t_{i+1}-t_{i})}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t^2}}\cdots e^{-\frac{x^2}{2(t_{n}-t_{n-1})^2}}dx_{1} \ldots dx_{n}=\frac{1}{C}P(B_{t_{1}}\in (-\infty,x_{1}], \ldots B_{t_{n}}\in (-\infty,x_{n}])$.

It thus looks like I differ by a constant $\frac{1}{C}$, could anyone see where I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you instead differ by a factor of $\frac{1}{c^n}$ since you should get a $\frac{1}{c}$ for each term in the product going between the last two lines. This results from you missing a constant factor $c$ each time you make the change of variables $x_i \mapsto c x_i$ between the first two lines.